# How to "clear cookies" in Chrome/Firefox for mTLS?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chromium, mutual-authentication, mtls

How do you tell Chrome to stop using a specific mTLS certificate to login to a website?

Whenever I connect to a website supporting mTLS (Mutual TLS), I get a prompt from my browser to pick a certificate to login to the website. (Just like the following)

[image]

You can try it out at this adress: http://testssl.asipsante.fr/

It happens that I picked the wrong certificate and I want to switch to another one. For development purposes I also want to be able to test multiple certificates one after the other.

Is there a way to reset/clear the certificate used for a specific domain inside Chrome?
Is it possible in Firefox?